# How can I recover a raid 5 single disk or entire array?

Tags: raid, mdadm, raid5

I have three disks that where part of an array on a debian box that will no longer boot. Im have installed them in a ubuntu 18.04 box and am attempting to mount them but get the error "can't read superblock on /dev/md127"

I have run

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdd to /dev/md/storage: Device or resource busy
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sde to /dev/md/storage: Device or resource busy
mdadm: /dev/md/storage has been started with 1 drive (out of 3).
```

Than I attempted to mount the one drive

```
/etc/mdadm$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME      SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0    98.4M squashfs          loop  /snap/telegram-desktop/270
loop1      87M squashfs          loop  /snap/core/5145
loop2   172.5M squashfs          loop  /snap/spotify/19
loop3   143.9M squashfs          loop  /snap/slack/7
loop4    98.5M squashfs          loop  /snap/telegram-desktop/274
loop5   141.5M squashfs          loop  /snap/slack/8
loop6    87.9M squashfs          loop  /snap/core/5328
sda     232.9G                   disk  
└─sda1  232.9G ext4              part  /
sdd     931.5G linux_raid_member disk  
sde     931.5G linux_raid_member disk  
sdf     931.5G linux_raid_member disk  
└─md127   1.8T                   raid5 
/etc/mdadm$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/md0
/etc/mdadm$ sudo mount /dev/sdf /mnt/md0
mount: /mnt/md0: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'.
/etc/mdadm$ sudo mount /dev/md127 /mnt/md0
mount: /mnt/md0: can't read superblock on /dev/md127.
/etc/mdadm$
```

Below is the mdadm examine output

```
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 3e82e98a:7050682c:c641e233:714b5b69
           Name : omv:storage
  Creation Time : Mon Sep 26 20:08:00 2016
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 1953263024 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
     Array Size : 1953262592 (1862.78 GiB 2000.14 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953262592 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=432 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 4d229594:462796ec:ee07bbc5:1f3234eb

    Update Time : Tue Aug 28 08:46:10 2018
       Checksum : 792d574c - correct
         Events : 262

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
~/Downloads$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sde
/dev/sde:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 3e82e98a:7050682c:c641e233:714b5b69
           Name : omv:storage
  Creation Time : Mon Sep 26 20:08:00 2016
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 1953263024 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
     Array Size : 1953262592 (1862.78 GiB 2000.14 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953262592 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=432 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 68199cc9:4ecea294:b2c95ef6:6a6e31eb

    Update Time : Tue Aug 28 08:46:10 2018
       Checksum : 86e1f37d - correct
         Events : 262

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
~/Downloads$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdf
/dev/sdf:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 3e82e98a:7050682c:c641e233:714b5b69
           Name : omv:storage
  Creation Time : Mon Sep 26 20:08:00 2016
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 1953263024 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
     Array Size : 1953262592 (1862.78 GiB 2000.14 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953262592 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=432 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 33e291e2:17dffadf:52c0d72d:3c5867f9

    Update Time : Tue Aug 28 08:46:10 2018
       Checksum : 30dead85 - correct
         Events : 262

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Updated output

```
:~$ sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md/storage
mdadm: stopped /dev/md/storage
:~$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md/storage assembled from 1 drive - not enough to start the array.
:~$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
:~$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0   98.4M squashfs          loop /snap/telegram-desktop/270
loop1     87M squashfs          loop /snap/core/5145
loop2  172.5M squashfs          loop /snap/spotify/19
loop3  143.9M squashfs          loop /snap/slack/7
loop4   98.5M squashfs          loop /snap/telegram-desktop/274
loop5  141.5M squashfs          loop /snap/slack/8
loop6   87.9M squashfs          loop /snap/core/5328
sda    232.9G                   disk 
└─sda1 232.9G ext4              part /
sdd    931.5G linux_raid_member disk 
sde    931.5G linux_raid_member disk 
sdf    931.5G linux_raid_member disk 
:~$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/md0
:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdf /mnt/md^C
:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdf /mnt/md0^C
:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdd /mnt/md0
mount: /mnt/md0: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'.
:~$ sudo mount /dev/sde /mnt/md0
mount: /mnt/md0: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'.
:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdf /mnt/md0
mount: /mnt/md0: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'.
```

Comment: Try stopping `sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md/storage` then run the `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan`.

Comment: I added the output to the main post

Comment: Try following through https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Recovery and see if it can't see your array